# Don’t open new window when mounting USB key

Tags: usb, nautilus

Every time I plug in a USB device or SD card, Nautilus brings up a new window at that path. I know that there used to be a configuration option to determine whether or not you want this to happen, but I can’t find it any more. So where can I deactivate this? I only want the device to be mounted, not brought up front.